# Ошибка создания подключения. Текст ошибки в сбитой кодировке

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

Создаю новое подключение в Dbeaver'е, но выскакивает ошибка, написанная в непонятно какой кодировке.
Как это победить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте поменять язык интерфеса на английский, может получится прочитать ошибку